# interpolation numerical methods

Tags: numerical-methods

I have translated this question into English so excuse me if it is not proper.

I am struggling to figure out how to solve the following question any directions would be greatly appreciated

> Let $F$ be the function defined as:
> $$F(x)=\sqrt{x-x^2}.$$

> Additionally, consider $p_2(x)$, a polynomial interpolation that passes through the points $x_1$, $x_2 = 1$, and $x_3 = 0$.

**Objective:**

> The goal is to determine the largest value of $x_1$ within the interval $(0, 1)$ that satisfies the equation:
> $$F(0.5) - p_2(0.5) = -0.25$$

I tried doing Lagrange interpolation, however, that leaves me with an equation that requires a root-finding method (I tried bisection) and I have not managed to find $x_1$ that satisfies the above requirement

Comment: To @NeedsToKnow: I edited your Q, but I am confused with your function $F(x)$. Please, check my edit...

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak : This is Matlab notation, appropriate if the answer is expected in Matlab code, but not so much here for a theoretical question without mentioning Matlab.

Comment: To @LutzLehmann: If you know how to improve formatting regarding function $F(x)$, please do it. Thanx!

Answer (score 2):

Any quadratic polynomial with $p_2(0)=p_2(1)=0$ has the form $p_2(x)=cx(1-x)$ for some $c$.

Then for the required value at the midpoint one gets $p_2(0.5)=F(0.5)+0.25=0.75=c\cdot 0.25$, so $c=3$. With $p_2(x_1)=F(x_1)$ one gets $3\sqrt{x_1(1-x_1)}=1$, which is a quadratic equation that should be easy to solve.